# .htaccess remove PHP extension conflicts with redirect url with variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect-uri

I have written code for changing the url from
https://example.com/speciality_details.php?id=23&name=anaesthesia
to this https://example.com/specialities/23/anaesthesia

Now I want to remove .php extension from every page but while I am adding code for removing extension the previous page that I redirected is showing not found.if I am adding a slash (/) at the end of the page name like https:example.com/about/ - then the CSS of that page is broken

Currently tried this code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule /$ - \[L,R=404\]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(\[^.\]+)$ $1.php \[L\]
RewriteRule ^doctor/([0-9]+)/([^\.]+)$ doctor_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^specialities/([0-9]+)/([^\.]+)$ speciality_details.php?id=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

I need both codes without conflicting with each other

Comment: If the CSS is broken, it is probably relative. Usually the easiest solution is to make it absolute.

Comment: For the rest, I will always point people to using a router script. Send **all** requests (for URLs that don't exist) to a single PHP file, and have _that_ file figure out which additional PHP files to load.

Comment: @Ann Please correct the formatting of the code block (use backtick-fencing or indent by 4 spaces - button on the editing toolbar). Unfortunately you've used backslash-escapes throughout the code as an attempt to format for display, so it can't now simply be formatted as a code block without making it wholly invalid.